# RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager insert item wrong position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm seeing odd behavior in a `RecyclerView` using a `GridLayoutManager` with 2 spans.

I'm trying to get two columns of items:

```
0 1
2 3
4 5
6 7
```

... and so on

To achieve this, I'm creating a `GridLayoutManager` like so:

```
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    gridLayoutManager.setOrientation(GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
```

Initially this behaves perfectly.  My items appear in the order I want them to.

However, I also need to be able to remove items from the list, and then undo the removal if the user acts quickly enough.

To remove items and then allow undo/insertion of the item back in, I have the following logic executed when a user hits a "remove" button in the `RecyclerView` items.

```
    final Item = mItems.getItem(position);
    mItems.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);

    // Give the user a chance to undo the removal
    Snackbar.make(getView(),
                  "Item Removed", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction(R.string.item_removed_snackbar_undo, new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    mItems.add(position, item);
                    notifyItemInserted(position);
                }
            }).show();
```

`mItems` represents the list of items in my adapter.  `position` represents the adapter position of the item that had the remove button clicked.

Removing items behaves perfectly.  I am able to remove items, and items animate to fill in the empty spaces.  However, when I try to undo the deletion and add the item back, the recycler view gets messed and empty spaces are inserted.  For example, if I had the following items, and I removed item 2, then undid the removal this is what would happen:

```
0 1
2 3
```

remove 2

```
0 1
3
```

add 2 back

```
0 1
2
3
```

At this point, an "empty" view exists where 3 should be placed (second row, second column).  If I query the size of the adapter I still get 4 items, but somehow the items are spread out to take 5 positions total.  Touching the empty space does nothing, but if I reorient/config change the layout goes back to

```
0 1
2 3
```

as expected.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Zach

Comment: i had a similar problem but after i while i realised that there was a case when onCreateViewHolder() method returns a cached RecyclerView.ViewHolder - onCreateViewHolder must always return a new instance of RecycleriView.ViewHolder or RecyclerView.ViewHolder which is created outside RecyclerView pool that bug created a lot of crashes too

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  My code always returns a new ViewHolder in my onCreateViewHolder() method, so I don't think that is to blame unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the problem!

I am calling `mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position)` after my logic to re-insert the item.  I mistakenly took this piece out of my code above as I thought it was unrelated (I will be much more careful in the future).

Anyways, it seems that having this call in results in the funky behavior.  If I removed that call everything works as expected.  I suspect it was canceling the animation or causing something else to not work properly.

Now I would still like to have my item visible (in case the user removed it, scroll such that it would be offscreen, and then hits undo), but I will figure that out later - this is good enough for now.